# variable collection name in mongodb shell using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

Using the mongo shell which is javascript:

```
db.collection.insert()
```

Can I allow the collections name to be dynamic so as to work with several collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just talking about the mongo shell:

```
var col = db.collection;
col.find()
```

And all other commands are quite valid. The same goes for the database:

```
var odb = db.getSiblingDB("other")
```

And now `odb` works on the "other" database.

```
odb.othercollection
```

Would be working with "othercollection" in the "other" database, while `db` was still the current one.

It's all just JavaScript, so anything for an "object" is valid.

Answer (score 11):

From the mongo shell:

You can create variable using var for collection name

```
var colName = "mytest"
```

and then execute all the operations on collections as below:

```
db[colName].find()

db[colName].rename("newName")
```

etc.
This will help you keep your collection name dynamic and can even update it keeping your commands same.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

here is my idea for this issue, check if it helps:

```
function insertIntoColumn(colName){
   if(!colName) {
       return;
   }
   return db[colName].insert();
}
```

Comment: why not just  `db[colName].insert();` ?

Comment: thanks for notice it. I'll update. Such a dump code, maybe I did some magic then remove it haha.

Answer (score 2):

```
// This seems to work too.

var collectionNames = ["collection1", "collection2"];
collectionNames.forEach(function(collectionName) {
    var collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);

    collection.find();
});
```